# Why does fragment-ktx include the activity-ktx library and what else does it include?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am just curious. If I have a fragment-ktx dependency, it completely includes all activity-ktx functions. Does it work vice versa? If I only have the activity-ktx dependency, is it not the same?

Comment: Dependencies can only go in one direction, for logical reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the repositories themselves to see the dependencies they all have. In this case, the `activity-ktx` package doesn't include `fragment-ktx`, whereas (like you said), `activity-ktx` is included in `fragment-ktx`.

The Maven repositories:
[`fragment-ktx`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.fragment/fragment-ktx/1.3.2)
[`activity-ktx`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.activity/activity-ktx/1.2.2)

Comment: So, does it mean, that if core-ktx, lifecycle-viewmodel, etc are present in that list, I can delete them from my build.gradle?

Comment: Yes exactly. However if they are all the same version, they're not downloaded twice. So if you find it more clear to still keep them there, there shouldn't be any drawbacks!